# Yard Light has Volts but no light

Tags: electrical

Mobile Home. Yard lights are "typically" tapped off the back of an outlet and buried in the ground. I have wired the wire from the house directly to the light bulb. I will worry about putting the light sensor in when I get the bulb to work. I have volts on the black wire..... and the same volts on the white wire. (Tested with a Klein voltage tester.) Am I right that there should be no volts on the white wire? I think this means that the white, common wire, is not going back to the common in the fuse box. The other lights on that circuit, CB #1, are all working fine making me think that wherever the tap in was done...the white wire has come loose.....? Then the problem will be finding the place where the tap was done....

Comment: Voltage can only be measured between two wires.  What two are you measuring when you say that the black wire has volts?  How many volts does it have, and are you sure the meter is on the AC voltage setting?

Comment: @JPhi1618 sounds like they might be using a non-contact voltage tester.

Comment: And, yard lights are generally low-voltage, not house voltage; what are we talking here?

Comment: Black wire, white wire, "typically" tapped off the back of an outlet, sounds like 120.  Sounds like codevio too.

Answer (score 1):

There should be 120 volts AC between the red and black wire.  Or sometimes, 12 volts DC.  If there is not, there is no power there.

Electrical power works in loops.  There need to be 2 wires involved or nothing happens.  The way we do electricity in the US, the white wire is one of those two wires, but it is kept as close to earth ground as possible, so it is called neutral.

One way power can fail is for the white (neutral) wire to become disconnected or damaged.   This breaks the loop, obviously.  And since it is not connected, it will pick up stray voltage by induction.  In which case you can see a weak phantom voltage on the neutral.   If a non-contact tester shows voltage on both, perhaps that has happened.

Answer (score 0):

If using a non contact tester when the circuit is complete the white wire will show power. Non contact testers detect the field created by current flow. Try replacing the lamp I have had bulbs short and not light in the past. Another thing to test is to remove the lamp then there should be no field detected on the white because the small induced voltage usually from the hot will not light a non contact tester. Last verify the power was wired correctly if the white is connected to the hot in the box both wires would be hot with no return path.